# Assign permission to user after document creation

Tags: 2010, permissions, sharepoint-server, document, roles

So, i've been trying to make for a while now a way to apply permission to the creator for a file when its added on a library.

its something like this i've been doing so far

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
   {
       SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(
           delegate()
           {
               EventFiringEnabled = true;
               SPSite site = new SPSite("http://localhost");
               SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();

               SPListItem item = web.Lists[properties.ListId].GetItemById(properties.ListItemId);
               SPUser creator = web.SiteUsers[item.File.Author.ToString()];
               SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment((SPPrincipal)creator);
               item.BreakRoleInheritance(true, false);

               roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(web.RoleDefinitions["Full Control"]);
               roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(web.RoleDefinitions["Read"]);
               roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(web.RoleDefinitions["Design"]);
               roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(web.RoleDefinitions["Contribute"]);

               item.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
           });
   }
}
```

I was expecting that with this code, every .docx file I added on the library would automatically set permission for the creator. Instead, it does nothing. The debugger tells me that he excecutes the code, but i can't tell why its not doing what i wanted to do...

ps.: Sometimes, depending on what i change on the code, it sets all the permissions for all the files(!!) on the folder, and sets limited access permission to the folder, instead of just changing on the file i just added.

Does someone knows how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not really a proponent of doing item level permissions per file, could you handle this by using the item level permission options in the library possibly so that the creator is the only one who can edit the file? Also have you tried adding an item.Update() after item.RoleAssignments.Add?

Comment: well, item.Update() helped, but this makes it so that on the folder the file was in, the user shows up as Limited Access, when he wasn't supposed to show at all (unless its a sharepoint thing...) and thus making all other files have limited access for this user, with the exception of the files he created.

Comment: That sounds right, since the file is in a library with other documents, it would show he has limited access. You can try verifying that access is correct by using the Check Permissions ribbon option.